# can we break the speed of light

Tags: visible-light, faster-than-light

I know this is impossible but I just want to know where I went wrong.
here's  my proposal:
Let us imagine that we have a source of light and a switch that are far one light year from us.
so it would take light one year to get to us.
If we had a very long rod that connects my hand to the switch. 
When I move the rod a little distance I will reach the swich. 
So the time needed for me to close the switch  is less than that made by light.right?
Would I break the speed of light this way?

Comment: Related: can we **brake** the speed of light?

All jokes aside, what entity exactly do you think is moving faster than light in your story?

Comment: I would think that any rod is compressible (and rarefactional), and therefore the movement of one end isn't immediately transferred to the other end.